# Combining color channels for an RGB image not working as expected

Tags: matlab, jpeg, rgb

I'm trying to do the following:

> Now, we will compress a color jpg image. After reading in the jpg
> image, notice that the dimensions of this image are x * y * 3 where
> the resolution of your picture is x * y pixels. The third dimension
> stands for the RGB (red/green/blue) color value. Perform low rank
> approximations to your color image by using the SVD of each RGB slice
> (so you will be using 3 SVDs).

Here is my code:

```
A = imread('../img/BabySophie.jpg');
red = A(:, :, 1);
display_color_approx(red, 'red', 1)
green = A(:, :, 2);
display_color_approx(green, 'green', 2)
blue = A(:, :, 3);
display_color_approx(blue, 'blue', 3)

function [] = display_color_approx(color_channel, color, channel_index)
%display_color_approx Compress a color jpg image.
%   Displays compressed images of a particular color channel along with
%   compression info.
[u, s, v] = svd(double(color_channel));
for r = [5, 20, 100]
    approx = u(:, 1:r) * s(1:r, 1:r) * v(:, 1:r)';
    figure, imagesc(approx), axis off
    title([color, '; r =' , num2str(r, '%d'), ]);
end
end
```

The SVG approximations are all looking fine.  I expect the first 3 images to be reddish, the next 3 images to be greenish, and the final 3 images to be bluish.  However, each set of three is the same.

I'm attaching the image I used for input.

[image: BabySophie]

I can also attach some or all of the output images, if asked for.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the picture happens to be almost monochromatic.  So the differences between the three groups of three are too subtle to be seen.

I tried again with a color wheel image and the results were quite obvious.

[image]